# How to send stream of data from client to server?

Tags: node.js, meteor, stream

I am trying to upload a pdf file from client to my server.
I know how to read a file using node js "fs" module but how to read a file which is not on my server (i.e is on client disk). There is a upload button which chooses the file and then from client side I want to send that file in stream to my server. And then I can write the stream into a file on my server.

How are the packages like [ostrio:Files](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files) doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files

Great package to ease the upload and storage of files :)

Hope it helps,
Regards,
Yann

Comment: Thank you for the reply , but I want to know how they are doing it (i.e how are they sending files from client to server)